# How can I compute a rotation-invariant angle of a vector connecting two other vectors?

Tags: vectors, rotations

Suppose I have the vectors $$\mathbf{x}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$\mathbf{x}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$$ I want to compute the "orientation" of the vector $$\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}.$$ such that this "orientation" is rotation-invariant. That is, if $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ are rotated, then the value of this orientation would be the same. An unsuccessful way of doing this would be to compute the angle between $\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1$ and the x-axis, but this angle will not be rotation-invariant. How can I compute the orientation of $\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1$ such that it is rotation-invariant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are looking for a vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that the angle between $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1$ before rotation of $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$, which is
$$
\arccos\left(\frac{\mathbf{v} \cdot (\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1)}{||\mathbf{v}|| \times ||\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1||}\right),
$$
is equal to the angle between $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1$ after rotation of $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$, which is
$$
\arccos\left(\frac{\mathbf{v} \cdot (\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}_1)}{||\mathbf{v}|| \times ||\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}_1||}\right),
$$
where $\mathbf{R}$ is a rotation matrix. Equating these two expressions yields
\begin{align}
\arccos\left(\frac{\mathbf{v} \cdot (\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1)}{||\mathbf{v}|| \times ||\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1||}\right) &= \arccos\left(\frac{\mathbf{v} \cdot (\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}_1)}{||\mathbf{v}|| \times ||\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}_1||}\right) \\ \\
\frac{\mathbf{v} \cdot (\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1)}{||\mathbf{v}|| \times ||\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1||} &= \frac{\mathbf{v} \cdot (\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}_1)}{||\mathbf{v}|| \times ||\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}_1||} \\ \\
\frac{\mathbf{v} \cdot (\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1)}{||\mathbf{v}|| \times ||\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1||} &= \frac{\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{R}(\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1)}{||\mathbf{v}|| \times ||\mathbf{R}(\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1)||}
\end{align}
Since $||\mathbf{x}|| = \sqrt{\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}}$, and since the dot product is invariant to rotation, then
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathbf{v} \cdot (\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1)}{||\mathbf{v}|| \times ||\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1||} &= \frac{\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{R}(\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1)}{||\mathbf{v}|| \times ||\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1||} \\ \\
\mathbf{v} \cdot (\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1) &= \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{R}(\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1)
\end{align}
Again, since the dot product is invariant to rotation, then this equation is true when:

- the vector $\mathbf{v}$ on the left-hand side is $\mathbf{x}_1$ and the vector $\mathbf{v}$ on the right-hand side is $\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}_1$, or
- the vector $\mathbf{v}$ on the left-hand side is $\mathbf{x}_2$ and the vector $\mathbf{v}$ on the right-hand side is $\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}_2$.

In other words, the angle between $\mathbf{x}_1$ or $\mathbf{x}_2$ and $\mathbf{x}_2 - \mathbf{x}_1$ is invariant to rotation.